# Bypass Validation Rule with Approver of Record

Tags: apex

Hi I Need to bypass a validation rule upon update of a record. There is a validation rule that if a Quote stage is 'For Approval' the record cannot be updated unless it's the Approver of the Record. There is a approval process involved in this scenario.

MY PLAN IS
create a bypass checkbox in Quote object which is updated to true if the record is being updated by the approver of the record, thus will bypass the validation rule.

My issue is how can I get the approver of the record?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this not standard feature that you approver can edit locked record...? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_create_recordeditability.htm&type=5

Comment: Agree with @Ayub . Are the records not getting locked while under approval process.

Comment: Well for Initial Submission Actions. There is only record lock but no way for the approver to edit the record.

Comment: Can not add image in comment, so adding answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's salesforce OOB feature that you can give Approver privilege to edit the record. To acheive that, you need to select below highlighted option at 3rd step in approval process configuration.

[image]

Comment: Hi so basically if I ticked that checkbox. if for example the record is assigned to a approver for approval. the approver can edit the record? @Ayub

Comment: @imajmdf ..yes..exactly..